# Unable to provide action for select using ng-options

Tags: angularjs

```
<select ng-change="updateFirmTimeZone(timeZoneId)" ng-model="timeZoneId" ng-options="timeZoneId as tz.offset for tz in availableTimezones"></select>
```

This `updateFirmTimeZone(timeZoneId)` is not calling. How to provide action for select ? Any other suggestion. please update. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tz.id as tz.offset for tz in availableTimezones
```

or

```
tz.timeZoneId  as tz.offset for tz in availableTimezones
```

instead

```
`timeZoneId as tz.offset for tz in availableTimezones`
```

**HTML:**

```
<select ng-change="updateFirmTimeZone(timeZoneId)" ng-model="timeZoneId" ng-options="tz.id as tz.offset for tz in availableTimezones"></select>
```